# Integrate $ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}(x)} }$?

Tags: calculus, integration

what is the answer of this question?$ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+\tan^{2}(x)}
}$? By transformation?

Comment: What is $1+(\tan x)^2$? I mean, how to write it in an other way? What is the définition of $tan(x)$?

Comment: Have you thought about breaking the interval of integration into two equal subintervals?

Comment: @FDP yes, it is true that you say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply basic trigonometry.

> $$1+\tan^2 x =\sec^2x$$

So the integral becomes 
$$ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+tan^{2}(x)}}$$
$$= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sec^2x}}$$
$$= \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{|\sec x|}$$
$$= \int_0^{\pi} |\cos x| dx$$
$$= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos x dx + \int_\frac{\pi}{2}^{\pi} (-\cos x) dx$$
$$= \sin x\large|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \sin x\large|_\frac{\pi}{2}^{\pi} $$
$$= 1-(-1)$$
$$= 2$$

Comment: You lost an absolute value along the way. The integrand is nonnegative.

Comment: @grand_chat Thanks for the help. Corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}}\space\text{d}x+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\tan(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\sec^2(x)\space\text{d}x$.

---

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{(u^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\space\text{d}u+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(u^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $u=\tan(s)$ and $\text{d}u=\sec^2(x)\space\text{d}s$.

---

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec^2(s)}}\space\text{d}s+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sec^2(s)}}\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\cos(s)\space\text{d}s+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(s)\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\left[\sin(s)\right]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}+\left[\sin(s)\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=$$
$$1+1=2$$